# Can I remove long timeouts from my Jmeter CSV results?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I am visualizing Jmeter results using Blazemeter Sense. It provides a lot of graphs, like Average Response time vs. Virtual Users. It also notes all of the 500 error response codes.

However, for those 500's, the results still show a 60000+ ms response time (elapsed before it times out). Obviously this destroys the Average Response time, as I want to show that number for the calls that succeeded, and worry about the error responses separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is going for [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) and provide `--success-filter true` parameter like:

1. [Run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui):

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. Invoke Filter Results Tool to remove failed responses:

   ```
   FilterResults.bat --output-file success-only.jtl --input-file result.jtl --success-filter true
   ```
3. Feed this `success-only.jtl` to the [BlazeMeter Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)

Demo:

[image]

You can install Filter Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/):

[image]